# How do I get the token ID of a user that I just created using firebase authentication on Node js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

This my code for creating the user

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
        const newUser = {
            email: req.body.email, 
            password: req.body.password, 
            confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword, 
            handle: req.body.handle, 
        };

    admin.auth().createUser({email: newUser.email, password: newUser.password})
        .then(data =>{
            console.log(admin.auth().currentUser.getIdToken());
            return res.status(201).json({message: `user ${data.uid} signed up successfully`});

        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.code});
        });
});
```

When I add a new user, I get the following error :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of undefined`

Comment: which firebase-admin version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The `createUser()` method in Firebase Admin SDK just creates a user in Firebase Auth and does not log user in. Also you cannot get a user's ID Token using Admin SDK. You must login using Firebase Client SDKs and then use `getIdToken()`.

An alternative is to use [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password) to get that user's information that also contains the ID Token. This is possible only because you have users email and password in the CF. I won't recommend using this method unless it's just required.

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {...};

  await admin.auth().createUser({email: newUser.email, password: newUser.password})
        
  // Login as user using Firebase REST API

  return res.status(201).json({...})
});
```